# How can we construct a skewed noise distribution using the maximum likelihood approach?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-ai

When the probability of observing a large positive error is larger than the probability
of observing a large negative error in binary classification, how can  this be modelled by a skewed noise distribution using the maximum likelihood approach?

The content is as follows:

From page 103 of: http://smlbook.org/book/sml-book-draft-latest.pdf

"Using the maximum likelihood approach, other assumptions about the noise or
insights into its distribution can be incorporated in a similar way in the regression
model (5.1). For instance, if we believe that the error is non-symmetric, in the sense
that the probability of observing a large positive error is larger than the probability
of observing a large negative error, then this can be modelled by a skewed noise
distribution. Using the negative log-likelihood loss is then a systematic way of
incorporating this skewness into the training objective."

Answer (score 0):

From Bayesian statistics maximizing the data likelihood given a hypothesis of a specific parametric statistical model to be regressed along with a specific noise as source randomness is equivalent to *minimizing* the negative log-likelihood (NLL) of a *specific* form, for instance, from your previous question you've already known for any linear regression model with a Gaussian distributed additive noise the maximum likelihood approach demands the form of squared error loss. Thus the maximum likelihood approach is a generic way for *systematically* constructing a loss function based on a parametric model of the observed data, *ad hoc* loss functions can be avoided in theory for any assumed generic parametric model with any generically distributed noise.

If the error is non-symmetric, then obviously you cannot assume it following the usual Gaussian or Laplace distributions, perhaps you could assume it following the [skew normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution), [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), etc. Of course for a linear regression model with a non-symmetric noise the NLL does not typically have a closed-form analytic solution, so to find the parameters minimizing the NLL would usually involve iterative numerical optimization methods such as gradient descents.